# starting redis as a service fails on redhat 6.1

Tags: linux, redhat, service, redis

I have installed redis on a redhat 6.1 linux machine.

I used the commands

`make
make install
cd utils
./install_server`

I used all default settings so I can start the server with the `redis-server` command.
Now I want to start is as a service, which should be feasible via `serviece redis_6379 start`.
However, I am getting the following output:

`[root@localhost ssl]# sudo service redis_6379 start
 exists, process is already running or crashed`

It seems to me that the system is not reading the `$PIDFILE` variable which, according to the script within `/etc/init.d/redis_6379` is read from the configuration file in `/etc/redis/6379.conf`.
Both files are as per the default configuration.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Below is the script in `/etc/init.d/redis_6379`

```
#!/bin/sh\n #Configurations injected by install_server below....\n\n EXEC=/usr/local/bin/redis-server\n CLIEXEC=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli\n PIDFILE=/var/run/redis_6379.pid\n CONF="/etc/redis/6379.conf"\n\n REDISPORT="6379"\n\n ###############\n\n

case "$1" in
    start)
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                echo "$PIDFILE exists, process is already running or crashed"
        else
                echo "Starting Redis server..."
                $EXEC $CONF
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                echo "$PIDFILE does not exist, process is not running"
        else
                PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
                echo "Stopping ..."
                $CLIEXEC -p $REDISPORT shutdown
                while [ -x /proc/${PID} ]
                do
                    echo "Waiting for Redis to shutdown ..."
                    sleep 1
                done
                echo "Redis stopped"
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Please use start or stop as first argument"
        ;;
esac
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the scrip `/etc/init.d/redis_6379`.

I don't know for what reason (maybe something solved, as this is from redis 2.6.7, but the first line was malformed. Once I turned it into

```
#!/bin/sh
#Configurations injected by install_server below....
EXEC=/usr/local/bin/redis-server
CLIEXEC=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli
PIDFILE=/var/run/redis_6379.pid
CONF="/etc/redis/6379.conf"
REDISPORT="6379"

###############
```

Tha whole thing started to work.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - If you used the init script provided here http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/utils/redis_init_script you'll have to add a `status` and `status_q` option in the init script for redis to appear properly if you're using `service --status-all` or else the service will appear with 'Please use start or stop as first argument'